# What determines the minimum CD recording speed?

Tags: windows-7, imgburn

While solving a problem with a device that was having trouble reading my recorded MP3 CD discs, some coleagues here suggested I try recording at lower speeds to see if that will help.

I'm using ImgBurn for recording. The CD discs I was using were designated for 52x recording speeds, but while trying to record them at 4x I noticed ImgBurn (and several other applications I tried to check, whether it is a recording application issue) switched the speed to 10x.

**What determines the minimum CD recording speed; the brand of the CD, the disc drive** (in this case a generic Lenovo laptop drive, I do not know the OIM or the particulars, but the laptop is fairly new, maybe a year old) **or something else?**

Comment: Usually it it the burning software that controls the speed.

Comment: @Moab - Why is it then that while setting the speed for 4x, upon inserting the disc in the drive, the speed gets reset to 10x as minimum?

Comment: Probably the software has determined 10x is the lowest safe speed for that media to burn at to avoid making coasters.